# How to implement Newton's Identities

Tags: replacement, core-language, variable-definitions

I need to produce identities related to [Newton's Identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities) of arbitrary order. More specifically, I need the identities in the following image for an arbitrary n:

[image]

What I can't quite wrap my head around is how to work with expressions in Mathematica where I don't know how many variables are involved. Is there a way to programatically create subscripted variables on the fly? So, basically, looking for help getting started.

Answer (score 3):

```
Format[p[x_] := Subscript[p, x]];
Format[e[x_] := Subscript[e, x]];
Table[p[k] == (-1)^(k - 1) e[k] k + 
    Sum[(-1)^(k - 1 + i) e[k - i] p[i], {i, 1, k - 1}], {k, 1, 
   10}] // Column
```

$$\begin{array}{l}
 p_1=e_1 \\
 p_2=e_1 p_1-2 e_2 \\
 p_3=-e_2 p_1+e_1 p_2+3 e_3 \\
 p_4=e_3 p_1-e_2 p_2+e_1 p_3-4 e_4 \\
 p_5=-e_4 p_1+e_3 p_2-e_2 p_3+e_1 p_4+5 e_5 \\
 p_6=e_5 p_1-e_4 p_2+e_3 p_3-e_2 p_4+e_1 p_5-6 e_6 \\
 p_7=-e_6 p_1+e_5 p_2-e_4 p_3+e_3 p_4-e_2 p_5+e_1 p_6+7 e_7 \\
 p_8=e_7 p_1-e_6 p_2+e_5 p_3-e_4 p_4+e_3 p_5-e_2 p_6+e_1 p_7-8 e_8 \\
 p_9=-e_8 p_1+e_7 p_2-e_6 p_3+e_5 p_4-e_4 p_5+e_3 p_6-e_2 p_7+e_1 p_8+9 e_9 \\
 p_{10}=e_9 p_1-e_8 p_2+e_7 p_3-e_6 p_4+e_5 p_5-e_4 p_6+e_3 p_7-e_2 p_8+e_1 p_9-10 e_{10} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 3):

It's not clear whether you need just a display or formal expression or an actual recursive function. I'll assume the latter.

```
p[1] = e[1];
p[n_] := 
  Simplify[
    Sum[e[i]*p[n - i]*(-1)^(1 + i), {i, 1, n - 1}] + 
    n*e[n]*(-1)^(1 + n)]
```

This was just a matter of coming up with an expression for `p[n]` that matched the pattern provided. I didn't try to simplify it any. The `Simplify` just forces the terms to be combined. You should test to verify it actually matches your expectation--it looks correct to me for a small set of terms.

Now, you mentioned subscripts. Subscripts are just notation, so a formal expression like `e[4]` can be interpreted as equivalent to a subscripted `e`. However, if you really want to see subscripts you can use this:

```
Format[e[n_]] := Subscript[e, n]
```

Execute the above before evaluating any specific `p`, and then you should see the nicely subscripted format when you do evaluate a specific `p`. Understand that this will just affect the display. The actual expressions will still use things like `e[5]`.

Since you provided the fully expanded expression on the far right hand side (the ones with just `e` and no `p`), then I'm assuming that you don't need to keep the intermediate form with `p`. If you do need that form, then we'd need to come up with something slightly different.